# for loop doesen't iterate over string in a function but does without function - python 3

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop

my code:

```
def word_distribution(stringeling):
    for char in "?!.,":
        Satz = stringeling.replace(char,"")
    return Satz

print(word_distribution("Hallo du Peter? Du! und punkt. und komma,"))

output: Hallo du Peter Du! und punkt. und komma
```

The code does only remove the first "?"  Why when i use the for loop without the function it prints me all the word without punctuation. Thanks for help ;)

Comment: Alright, we need a canonical question for people who assign to the wrong variable in a loop. I swear I've seen a dozen questions like this one recently.

Comment: I don't think it will remove the question mark, but only the final comma. Strings in python are immutable, each operation on the string will return a new string.

Comment: Works great know thanks! @Aran-Fey sorry i found similair questions in the search but they all forgett the return statement ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
def word_distribution(stringeling):
    for char in "?!.,":
        stringeling = stringeling.replace(char,"")
    return stringeling.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

you overwrite Satz every time in the loop with the original stringeling. Try:

```
def word_distribution(stringeling):
    for char in "?!.,":
        stringeling = stringeling.replace(char,"")
    return stringeling


print(word_distribution("Hallo du Peter? Du! und punkt. und komma,"))
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you don't really need a for loop. Since replace does a fixed replacement hence, I used sub from re module to do search and replace using regex. Below is the code

```
        import re
        def word_distribution(stringeling):
            Satz = re.sub('[?,.!]',"",stringeling,count=0,flags=0)
            return Satz
```

Output as follows

```
>>> print(word_distribution("Hallo du Peter? Du! und punkt. und komma,"))
Hallo du Peter Du und punkt und komma
```

Refer - [Read documentation on re.sub here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)